# Is it good practice to use the same page to show user information based on the role/ID?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, authorization

I have a page in my web application that displays Documents associated with the currently logged-in user (by an ID that is retrieved using cookie-based authentication upon logging in), where they can download them or upload new ones.

However, if the logged-in user is an Admin, they may pass an ID in the request and see that particular user's documents.

My question is, is this a safe approach and guarantees that a normal user can't potentially somehow see some other user's documents, or should there be a separate page, only accessible by admins, to be used to display any user's documents?

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OnGet(string? id)
        {

            //First check if the user is an Admin
            if (User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Role) == "Admin")
            {

                //If the user is an admin and an ID is provided, retrieve documents of that ID (if it exists)
                if (id != null)
                {
                    UserInfo = await _firebaseHelper.GetUserByIDAsync(id);
                    if (UserInfo != null)
                    {
                        documents = /*call function that retrieves documents from cloud*/
                        return Page();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Redirect them to their documents (without ID)
                        return RedirectToPage("Documents");
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //If the user is not an Admin, check if they are trying to retrieve other documents by passing an ID
                if (id != null)
                {
                    //Redirect them to their documents (without ID)
                    return RedirectToPage("Documents");
                }
            }

            //Otherwise retrieve the current user's documents
            var userID = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            UserInfo = await _firebaseHelper.GetUserByIDAsync(userID);
            documents = /*call function that retrieves documents from cloud*/

            return Page();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is a good approach, because you are managing one resource and giving appropriate permissions for every role needing them.

Comment: But is there a potential that somehow the page will bug out and show another user's documents if they are not an admin? For example if the session expires, etc.

Comment: If OnGet is properly Authorized/Authenticated you shouldn't have any problem. If authentication is custom then you should check for expired sessions manually.